# QT capture data from 3 continous brackets

Tags: regex, windows, qt

i have string in a file which i want to extract data from using regex

```
Friday 29 July 2014_06:34:56  IST [GPS   ] [18.2463  ] [72.6321   ]   device status [OK] [13] [wait10] connected.
```

// I want to get GPS,LATT,LONG in some what like

```
QStringList data;

data[0]="[GPS   ]";

data[1]="[18.245  ]";

data[2]="[72.234  ]";
```

but i am getting single string

```
data[0]=**"[GPS   ] [18.245  ] [72.234  ]"**
```

i dont want to use split

//currently using

```
**QRegExp exp("((\\[.*\\])+ )");**
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: in python:
pattern=re.compile(r".*? (\\[.*?\\]) (\\[.*?\\]) (\\[.*?\\]) .*?")
y=pattern.match(x).groups()
print y...........
you can try something like dis...

Comment: you should use non greedy regex `"((\\[.*?\\])+ )"` that the construct
`.*?` will stop when it reaches the first closing bracket

Comment: .? some what helped me but not able to solve completely, I am able separate out 2 square brackets but not the last one so falling back to split method. regex (\[.*?\]) (\[.*?\]) (\[.*?\]) parsed data somewhat same which i am getting in single QString.

Answer (score 1):

Non greedy regex should solve your problem:

your regex `**QRegExp exp("((\\[.*\\])+ )");**` will match all between an opening bracket and a closing bracket but `.*` is greedy and will match to the end and do backstepping then

if you use `**QRegExp exp("((\\[.*?\\])+ )");**` it will only match characters up to the first closing bracket, which is what u like to have.